# Use default JSON parser in Fastify addContentTypeParser

Tags: javascript, fastify

Good day,

Please help with reaching **fastify** default parser.

What I need is assign JSON-body parser on every request regardless `content-type` header

Currently, I have done it with that ugly workaround:

```js
const {kContentTypeParser} = require("fastify/lib/symbols")
const asJson = fastify[kContentTypeParser].customParsers["application/json"]
fastify.addContentTypeParser("*", asJson);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should open a feature request to get it because it is not exposed. But I would change approach if you want to use always the JSON parser, like add a `onRequest` hook that overwrites the `content-type` with `application/json` to every request.

Comment: Definitely, the hook is the more elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fastify <=v2.11 the default content type parser is not exposed.

Since it applies many checks (like prototype poisoning, content length, etc..) you should be careful before overwrite.

Your target can be archived adding an hook:

```
fastify.addHook('onRequest', (request, reply, done) => {
  const type = request.getHeader('content-type')
  if(!type || type.indexOf('json') < 0){
    // force json body parse
    request.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
  }
  done()
})
```