# How to add custom content type parser for Nest with Fastify

Tags: nest, fastify, nestjs-fastify

I need to overwrite the content parser for `application/json` so my application accepts empty body. Right now it throws:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "code": "FST_ERR_CTP_EMPTY_JSON_BODY",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Body cannot be empty when content-type is set to 'application/json'"
}
```

I'm trying with:

```
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

const fastifyAdapter = new FastifyAdapter({
   addContentTypeParser: // what should go here
});

const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, fastifyAdapter);
```

but I can't figure out what is expected under `addContentTypeParser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow empty json body, you can add a content body parser like the following. Instead of throwing `FST_ERR_CTP_EMPTY_JSON_BODY` error, this will set request body to `null`.

```js
const fastifyAdapter = new FastifyAdapter();

fastifyAdapter.getInstance().addContentTypeParser(
  'application/json',
  { bodyLimit: 0 },
  (_request, _payload, done) => {
    done(null, null);
  }
);
```

You can also set the request body to any value you want using the second argument of the done method.

Setting body to an empty object for example, would be look like this:

```js
const fastifyAdapter = new FastifyAdapter();

fastifyAdapter.getInstance().addContentTypeParser(
  'application/json',
  { bodyLimit: 0 },
  (_request, _payload, done) => {
    done(null, {});
  }
);
```

---

Also, for those who are getting `FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE` error like me, adding a catch-all content type parser for empty body requests fixes the issue.

```js
const fastifyAdapter = new FastifyAdapter();

fastifyAdapter.getInstance()
  .addContentTypeParser(
    '*',
    { bodyLimit: 0 },
    (_request, _payload, done) => {
      done(null, null);
    }
  );
```

Tus clients, by default sends a `POST` request with no `content-type` and an empty body. Using a catch-all parser fixed my problem.

Comment: Throws error because fastify have default json parser, and I don't want to replace with my own parser

Comment: this turns any body into null for me

Answer (score 2):

Because `request.body` will still null in [`onRequest`](https://fastify.dev/docs/v3.29.x/Reference/Hooks/#onrequest) and [`preParsing`](https://fastify.dev/docs/v3.29.x/Reference/Hooks/#preparsing). Check `body` from header `content-length`

```js
const fastify = Fastify({
  // logger: true,
});

fastify.addHook('preParsing', (request, reply, payload, done) => {
    if (
      ['POST', 'DELETE'].includes(request.method) &&
      request.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json' &&
      request.headers['content-length'] == '0'
    ) {
      delete request.headers['content-type'];
  }

  done();
});

const fastifyAdapter = new FastifyAdapter(fastify);
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, fastifyAdapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the error `FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE` because I was getting a PUT request with `application/json` in `Content-Type` header with empty body for a particular url.

I fixed the issue with a custom hook that fixes the request before passing it to the adapter. I don't know if your solution is better, but this looks cleaner to me:

```
const adapter = nestApp.getHttpAdapter();
const instance = adapter.getInstance();
instance.addHook('onRequest', (request, _reply, done) => {
    const contentType = request.headers['content-type'];
    const method = request.raw.method;
    const url = request.url;

    if (
        method === 'PUT' &&
        contentType === 'application/json; charset=utf-8' &&
        url.startsWith('/example')
    ) {
        delete request.headers['content-type'];
    }

    done();
});
```

I was inspired by this question: [Use default JSON parser in Fastify addContentTypeParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532309/use-default-json-parser-in-fastify-addcontenttypeparser)

Comment: Notice: in the onRequest hook, request.body will always be null, because the body parsing happens before the preValidation hook. https://fastify.dev/docs/v3.29.x/Reference/Hooks/#onrequest